# How to commit backlog item to a sprint using Hansoft SDK

Tags: sdk

I am trying to add backlog items to sprint using Hansoft SDK.

There is a function "HPMFunctionTask**Get**LinkedToSprint" which gets an ID of sprint to which is a task linked. Unfortunately there is no function to **set** the sprint of a task, in the SDK.

Is there any way to commit an item to a sprint?

In GUI it looks like this:
[image: Add backlog item to a sprint]

Thank you,
OndraS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got an answer from Hansoft support.

To add  backlog item to a sprint I have to create a proxy item:

```
HPMTaskCreateUnified ProxyTaskCreate = new HPMTaskCreateUnified();
ProxyTaskCreate.m_Tasks = new HPMTaskCreateUnifiedEntry[1];
HPMTaskCreateUnifiedReference Parent = new HPMTaskCreateUnifiedReference();
HPMTaskCreateUnifiedReference Previous = new HPMTaskCreateUnifiedReference();
Parent.m_bLocalID = false;
Parent.m_RefID = Sprint.UniqueID.m_ID; // the task reference id of the sprint
Previous.m_bLocalID = false;
Previous.m_RefID = Sprint.UniqueID.m_ID; // the task reference id of the sprint
ProxyTaskCreate.m_Tasks[0] = new HPMTaskCreateUnifiedEntry();
ProxyTaskCreate.m_Tasks[0].m_bIsProxy = true;
ProxyTaskCreate.m_Tasks[0].m_LocalID = 0;
ProxyTaskCreate.m_Tasks[0].m_TaskType = EHPMTaskType.Planned;
ProxyTaskCreate.m_Tasks[0].m_TaskLockedType = EHPMTaskLockedType.BacklogItem;
ProxyTaskCreate.m_Tasks[0].m_ParentRefIDs = new HPMTaskCreateUnifiedReference[1];
ProxyTaskCreate.m_Tasks[0].m_ParentRefIDs[0] = Parent;
ProxyTaskCreate.m_Tasks[0].m_PreviousRefID = Previous;
ProxyTaskCreate.m_Tasks[0].m_Proxy_ReferToRefTaskID = Task.UniqueID.m_ID; // Task ref in backlog that we want to commit
Previous.m_bLocalID = true;
Previous.m_RefID = 0;
HPMChangeCallbackData_TaskCreateUnified ProxyResult = m_Session.TaskCreateUnifiedBlock(ProjectID, ProxyTaskCreate);
```

It is very dumpy-looking, but working. At the end, all I had to change on this code is the name of sprint and task variable.

OndraS